# Look-and-feel issue when centering JTable column header

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtableheader

I am using the following code:

```
public final class TableCellRendererCenter extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public static final TableCellRenderer INSTANCE
            = new TableCellRendererCenter();

    protected TableCellRendererCenter() {

        // Calling super
        super();

        this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    }

}
```

on a JTable column:

```
    TableColumnModel retrMod = ChartItemsTable.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn retrCol = retrMod.getColumn(2);

    retrCol.setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRendererCenter.INSTANCE);
    retrCol.setCellRenderer(TableCellRendererCenter.INSTANCE);
```

and the look-and-feel does not match other column headers anymore:

[image]

Why? How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

It seems like NetBeans is using `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` which is coming from `package sun.swing.table;`

I read everywhere that I should not use sun packages. Grrrr... this does not help!

**EDIT 2**

The suggestion of 0verbose produces the following:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Following eugener's suggestion, I updated my code as following:

```
public final class TableCellRendererCenter extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        // returns component used for default header rendering
        // makes it independent on current L&F

        Component retr = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().
            getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if ( JLabel.class.isAssignableFrom(retr.getClass()) ) {

            JLabel jl = (JLabel) retr;
            jl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        }

        return retr;

    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {}

    @Override
    public void revalidate() {}

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChange(
        String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChange(
        String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}

}
```

And I get this:

[image]

Look-and-feel is preserved and column header is centered !!! (Other column headers are centered too, but I can control this by making further tests on the `int row, int column` parameters).

Comment: I think you mean that the background, color, etc. no longer matches the other columns, no? (*Layout* has to do with where things go, not how they look).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Totally off to one side, and a nit-pick, but `// Calling super` is one of those stereotypically useless "well DUH!" code comments which should just never be done.

Comment: I agree, in this case, it's useless, but it is no harm. In other cases, I usually explain why I call super with this and that parameters for documentation purposes.

Comment: I suggest using the code I provided as common class and then inherit your specific renderers from it

Comment: `JLabel.class.isAssignableFrom(retr.getClass())` can be written as `retr instanceof JLabel`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are using different cell renderer then the one used by your LAF. IMO the only way to achieve proper LAF is to **use renderer already provided by LAF itself** such as:

```
public class TableHeaderRenderer extends JComponent implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                // returns component used for default header rendering
                // makes it independent on current L&F

        return table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().
                          getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        }

        // following methods are overriden for performance reasons

        @Override
        public void validate() {}

        @Override
        public void revalidate() {}

        @Override
        public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}

        @Override
        public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}

}
```

Obviously, once you have proper renderer, you can cast it to a JLabel (after checking that it is, of course) and then center your text or do something else.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try refactor yourclass this way :

```
public class TableCellRendererCenter extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{

public TableCellRendererCenter(JTable associatedTable){

    this.table = associatedTable;
    JTableHeader header = this.table.getTableHeader();

    this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    this.setForeground(header.getForeground());
    this.setBackground(header.getBackground());
    this.setFont(header.getFont());

}
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    return this;

}}
```

EDIT:
I checked right now. [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) already extends JComponent.  So it's possible that only these lines are needed:

```
this.setForeground(header.getForeground());
this.setBackground(header.getBackground());
this.setFont(header.getFont());
```

(I'm not sure. I did something similar but not for column header and not extending DefaultTableCellRenderer)

Comment: I just tried, but it does not solve the issue. See the update in my question.